# How to submit edited data to object in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I press accept button task should be updated with new value which I wrote in input.Sad thing it doesnt work like I want.Do i need to add id`s to array with objects?

or maybe there is some good method to send a object to function.Here`s  the code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>
            <!--  $index-->
        </td>
        <td>{{task.taskName}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="statusCheck"> </td>
        <td style="{{setStyleToTd(statusCheck)}}">{{statusChecker(statusCheck)}}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editTask(task)">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-8 edit-box" ng-show="editBoxShow">
    <form action="" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <lable>Edit task here:</lable>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="editTaskInput"> </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="acceptEdit()">Accept</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div> 

$scope.editTask = function(taskToEdit) {
    $scope.editBoxShow = true;
    $scope.editTaskInput = taskToEdit.taskName;
}
$scope.acceptEdit = function() {
    $scope.editBoxShow = false;
    $scope.taskToEdit = $scope.editTaskInput;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the index of your table data while clicking edit button and then update the table data by using this index in acceptEdit function.

```
$scope.editTask = function (taskToEdit) {
    $scope.selectedIndex=$scope.tasks.indexOf(taskToEdit);
    $scope.editBoxShow = true;
    $scope.editTaskInput = taskToEdit.taskName;
}

 $scope.acceptEdit = function () {
    $scope.editBoxShow = false;
    $scope.tasks[$scope.selectedIndex].taskName=$scope.editTaskInput;
}
```